# Highest version of mySQL and PHP for EE 1.7.3

Tags: php, ee1, mysql

My hosting company needs to upgrade my server to the latest versions of PHP and mySQL. The problem is I'm running a number of EE sites varying between versions 1.6.8 and 1.7.3.

So what is the highest version of PHP and mySQL that I can successfully run EE1.7.3 on? This is just a stopgap solution until I can get my clients to upgrade to EE2.x

On the EllisLab site I can only find the minimum requirements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What versions would they like to put you on?  I think there are not likely to be any issues in MySQL versions.  But could be on PHP especially with third party add ons.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The versions they would like to upgrade to are MySQL 5.6x and PHP 5.4x (minimum preferably 5.5x).

Comment: Did you run into any issues on this? I'm about to move a few EE1 sites to a new server.

Comment: Hi Garrett. No issues in relation to MySQL but you need to watch your versions of PHP. On my local environment I installed my backups of the EE1.x installation using PHP 5.1.6 and once they were upgraded switched the version of PHP in MAMP to 5.4.34 - I've found that EE2.x doesn't play nicely with PHP versions higher than that. Hope that helps.